# route not defined in laravel 8 resource

Tags: php, laravel-8

i want to add a function to my resource controller. i've read some articles that said we have to put the route line before the resource line and that is what i did. but i still get and error that says route not defined.

```
    Route::name('panel.')->prefix('panel')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {

        Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name("dashboard");

        Route::resource('contact', ContactController::class)->only([
            'index', 'show', 'destroy'
        ]);
        Route::post('/portfolio' , [PortfolioController::class, 'visibility']);

        Route::resource('portfolio', PortfolioController::class)->except([
            'show'
        ]);

        Route::resource('customer', CustomerController::class)->except([
            'show'
        ]);

        Route::resource('advice', AdviceController::class)->only([
            'index', 'destroy'
        ]);

        Route::resource('invoice', InvoiceController::class)->only([
            'index', 'destroy', 'create', 'store',
        ]);
        Route::resource('email', EmailTemplateController::class)->only([
            'index', 'destroy', 'create', 'store',
        ]);

        Route::resource('profile', ProfileController::class)->only([
            'update', 'index', 'destroy'
            /*
             * index
             * destroy
             */
        ]);

        Route::get('/me', [ProfileController::class, 'show'])->name("profile.show");


    });
```

this is my web.php
the name of the route should be panel.portfolio.visibility.
also another thing i did not write the code to this project im just adding a few features to it. so the new function is mine but not the resource controller.

```
    public function visibility(Request $request,$portfolio_id)
        {
            $portfolio= Portfolio::find($portfolio_id);
            if($portfolio instanceof Portfolio){
                $this->validate($request,[],[]);
                $indicator = ($request->input('custom-switch-checkbox') == 'on') ? 1 : 0;
                $newData= ['portfolio_visibility' => $indicator];
                $portfolio->update($newData);
                return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'با موفقیت به روز رسانی گردید.');
            }
        }
```

this is my visibility function.
there is this page that shows the list of the portfolios and there is a column where theres a switch that indicates if the portfolio should be shown or not.
i can create portfolios just fine but i cant enter the list page which is the index page here.

```html
<td>
                                                    <!--dokme baraye namayesh -->
                                                    <form action="{{ route('panel.portfolio.visibility' , $portfolio->portfolio_id ) }}" role="form" method="post">
                                                        <label class="custom-switch mt-2" >
                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="custom-switch-checkbox"
                                                                   class="custom-switch-input"
                                                                   id="personal-data-button" {{($portfolio->portfolio_visibility== 0)? '': 'checked'}} onclick="{{ route("panel.portfolio.visibility" , $portfolio->portfolio_id ) }}">
                                                            <span class="custom-switch-indicator"></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </form>
                                                </td>
```

this is in the index.blade.php
i dont know why theres a problem.
also i am fairly new to laravel so if my question is confusing or sounds stupid please be kind.

Comment: _name of the route should be `panel.portfolio.visibility`_ I don't see any route named like this. You can run `php artisan route:list` to see all your routes and their name

Comment: The documentation has a list of [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Answer (score 0):

When you use Route::resource it does it for you with default naming convention. If you use Route::post you have to specify the name like it is done in your dashboard route.

So changing your route this way should work:

```
Route::post('/portfolio' , [PortfolioController::class, 'visibility'])->name('portfolio.visibility');
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes

Answer (score -1):

as for me there were codes I comment out which the error occurs. I deleted those and all turns fine.